# symmetric algebra of a (co)chain complex

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the symmetric tensor algebra of a vector space $V$
$$
\mathrm{Sym} (V) =\oplus_{m\ge 0} \mathrm{Sym}^m (V)
$$
Suppose $V$ happens to be a chain complex with a differential $d:V\to V$ such that $d\circ d=0$.
Then, is $\mathrm{Sym}(V)$ also a chain complex? If so, how does the differential look like?

Comment: The induced one. Do you know what $Sym^m(V)$ is as a graded module?